# Как отправлять форму без кнопки submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, form, redux-form

Использую `React` и библиотеку `redux-form`. Хочу сделать форму, которая будет отправляться по событию `onBlur`. Есть компонент:

```
const UpdateTargetForm = ({handleSubmit, error, close}) => {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Field name={"field"} component={"input"} onBlur={???}/>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Какую функцию написать в `onBlur`, чтобы происходила отправка формы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Какую функцию написать в onBlur, чтобы происходила отправка формы?

Функцию отправки формы которую вы написали на одну строку выше.

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
     <Field name={"field"} component={"input"} onBlur={handleSubmit/>
</form>
```

Вот рабочий код без библиотеки:

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const submitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("submits", value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
        <input
          {...{ value }}
          onBlur={submitForm}
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**UPD**
Пример с redux-form [**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-johnson-bqp2p?file=/src/index.js)

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";

let App = () => {
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submit");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field name={"field"} component={"input"} onBlur={handleSubmit} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App = reduxForm({
  form: "contact"
})(App);
```

Comment: Увы, но `<Field name={"field"} component={"input"} onBlur={handleSubmit}/>` не работает к сожалению. У вас работало? Может быть я ошибку где-то допустил (хотя вроде нет)

Comment: @Zhenyria обновил ответ, добавил пример с redux-form все работает. Проверьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: А, я понял. Вы используете собственную функцию handleSubmit. В принципе вариант-то хороший, я просто использовал handleSubmit, который мне даёт redux-form, вот с ним почему-то не работало

Comment: В принципе-то тогда лучше буду использовать ваш вариант без библиотеки. Выигрыша от redux-form в данном случае всё равно нет.

Comment: @Zhenyria если хотите использовать библиотеку советую `react-hook-form`.Я использовал практически все популярные библиотеки для работы с формами и мне понравилось только `react-hook-form`.

Comment: Да, мне её рекомендовали уже, но пока с единственной проблемой столкнулся и не хочется из-за этого весь проект переписывать :)